# Yii RBAC operation in different tasks

Tags: yii, role, rbac

I ran into interesting situation.
I have 2 roles. First - child, second - parent. And i have operation 'users.update' in task 'own.profile' in my child-role, like this:

```
Task: own.profile
  Operation: users.update
  Operation: users.view
```

So, there is another task, but in second-parent role:

```
Task: company.users.control
  Operation: users.create
  Operation: users.delete
  Operation: users.update
  Operation: users.view
```

Is it ok or something went wrong in my roles structure? Which one task will be invoked if i try checkAccess('users.update') with second-parent role?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured out RBAC's behavior:

I'm using CDbAuthManager, so in every checkAccess we invoke code:

```
$parents=$this->db->createCommand()
         ->select('parent')
         ->from($this->itemChildTable)
         ->where('child=:name', array(':name'=>$itemName))
         ->queryColumn();
foreach($parents as $parent){
     if($this->checkAccessRecursive($parent,$userId,$params,$assignments))
         return true;
}
```

So, Yii fetches all parents of item and checks if there is one of them returning true. If none - return false. First successful check breaks loop and return true.

Comment: Upvoted, for solving your own problem, and for posting back the solution.